# Nesting in JSON

Tags: arrays, json

I can't get the JSON below to validate. It crashes here:

```
"Head Coach": ["Baseball", "Basketball - Boys", "Basketball", "Volleyball - Girls", "Volleyball", "Spiritline"]
```

Without the last array it is fine. Any ideas?

---

```
{
    "userprofileid": 12547,
    "email": "cusdtrojans@gmail.com",
    "first_name": "Maribel",
    "middle_name": null,
    "last_name": "Vasquez",
    "prefix": null,
    "suffix": null,
    "schools": [{
        "schoolid": 417,
        "name": "Clifton High School",
        "addr": "4523 Appaloosa St.",
        "addr2": null,
        "city": "Clifton",
        "state": "AZ",
        "zip": "85533",
        "roles": ["Athletic Director",
            "Principal Secretary",
            "Theatre",
            "Media Adviser",
            "Webmaster",
            "Head Coach": ["Baseball", "Basketball - Boys", "Basketball", "Volleyball - Girls", "Volleyball", "Spiritline"]
        ]
    }]
}
```

Comment: Any JSON validator should point out exactly where the error was found.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

{ "userprofileid": 12547, "email": "cusdtrojans@gmail.com", "first_name": "Maribel", "middle_name": null, "last_name": "Vasquez", "prefix": null, "suffix": null, "schools": [{ "schoolid": 417, "name": "Clifton High School", "addr": "4523 Appaloosa St.", "addr2": null, "city": "Clifton", "state": "AZ", "zip": "85533", "roles": ["Athletic Director", "Principal Secretary", "Theatre", "Media Adviser", "Webmaster", "Head Coach", ["Baseball", "Basketball - Boys", "Basketball", "Volleyball - Girls", "Volleyball", "Spiritline"] ] }] }

`"Head Coach":` should be `"Head Coach",`
Here is the formatted version.

```
{
   "userprofileid":12547,
   "email":"cusdtrojans@gmail.com",
   "first_name":"Maribel",
   "middle_name":null,
   "last_name":"Vasquez",
   "prefix":null,
   "suffix":null,
   "schools":[
      {
         "schoolid":417,
         "name":"Clifton High School",
         "addr":"4523 Appaloosa St.",
         "addr2":null,
         "city":"Clifton",
         "state":"AZ",
         "zip":"85533",
         "roles":[
            "Athletic Director",
            "Principal Secretary",
            "Theatre",
            "Media Adviser",
            "Webmaster",
            "Head Coach",
            [
               "Baseball",
               "Basketball - Boys",
               "Basketball",
               "Volleyball - Girls",
               "Volleyball",
               "Spiritline"
            ]
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: You can copy and paste the JSON in https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ and it will tell you whether your JSON is valid or not.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, this ensures that you have a reference by the name of 'Head Coach' to the list.

```
{
    "userprofileid": 12547,
    "email": "cusdtrojans@gmail.com",
    "first_name": "Maribel",
    "middle_name": null,
    "last_name": "Vasquez",
    "prefix": null,
    "suffix": null,
    "schools": [{
        "schoolid": 417,
        "name": "Clifton High School",
        "addr": "4523 Appaloosa St.",
        "addr2": null,
        "city": "Clifton",
        "state": "AZ",
        "zip": "85533",
        "roles": [
            "Athletic Director",
            "Principal Secretary",
            "Theatre", "Media Adviser",
            "Webmaster", {
                "Head Coach": [
                    "Baseball",
                    "Basketball - Boys",
                    "Basketball",
                    "Volleyball - Girls",
                    "Volleyball",
                    "Spiritline"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }]
}
```

Comment: This JSON validates, but it probably does not do what the OP wants, which is to associate the various sports like `Baseball` with the role as `Head Coach`.

Comment: Can't we access Head Coach in this JSON? If we can, then we can access the list members as well.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, the below will be invalid

```
"roles": ["Athletic Director",
    "Principal Secretary",
    "Theatre",
    "Media Adviser",
    "Webmaster",
    "Head Coach": ["Baseball", "Basketball - Boys", "Basketball", "Volleyball - Girls", "Volleyball", "Spiritline"]
]
```

because `roles` is an array, yet you are trying to include in it the thing `"Head Coach":` which looks like a property that would be in an object.

The problem is with your data model: you want individual roles specified as strings in an array, but for the role of `Head Coach` you want additional information, namely the sports of which the person is head coach. I would recommend making `roles` an object, with the roles as properties, and a value of `true` if you simply want to specify that role with no additional information:

```
"roles": {
  "Athletic Director": true,
  "Principal Secretary": true,
  "Theatre": true,
  "Media Adviser": true,
  "Webmaster": true,
  "Head Coach": [
    "Baseball", 
    "Basketball - Boys", 
    "Basketball", "Volleyball - Girls", 
    "Volleyball", 
    "Spiritline"
  ]
}
```

Here is a real simple example of using this:

```
Object.keys(roles).forEach(role => {
  const value = roles[role];

  if (Array.isArray(value)) {
    console.log(role, 'of', value.join(', '));
  } else if (value === true) {
    console.log(role);
  } else {
    console.error(role, "has unknown value");
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the help/lesson @torazaburo.  It is greatly appreciated. Your recommendation of changing the data model makes great sense. I'll be implementing shortly.